# Python Django error : version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined

Tags: python, django

I have a python Django project. When I run its manage.py script as `manage.py runserver` via the virtual env, I get the following import error. **NOTE:** I am using Fedora 26

```
ImportError:
 /home/xxxxx/Projects/Dev/yyyy/ENV/new_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/.libs/libresolv-2-c4c53def.5.so:
symbol __res_maybe_init, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file
libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

What may be the reason?

Answer (score 13):

Finally, I could find the solution. I was using an old version of

> psycopg2

. So, I removed previously installed version with `pip uninstall psycopg2` and reinstalled it as `pip install psycopg2`

Comment: But why? Had the problem after migrating from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04

Comment: Faced the same issue suddenly in my live system. Fixed by upgrading psycopg2. Any idea what can be the cause?

Answer (score 12):

Was facing the same Issue worked after Installing:

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```